# How to get child element of default scrollbar(e.g. repeatbutton, thumb, etc.) in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've listbox which has some collection binded & once the content size gets increased listbox gets vertical scrollviewer(default) visible. I got scrollbar from this scrollviewer as child element. But, when I'm trying to get child element (e.g. repeatbutton, thumb) from scrollbar then i get child element null. I got control hierarchy from **silverlight spy**. I want to get repeatbutton from vertical scrollabr(This is not custom scrollbar). For e.g.
Code :

```
var objVRepeatBtn = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(objvScrollBar, 0)).FindName("VerticalSmallIncrease") as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RepeatButton;
```

Any approach will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with approach like :

```
private RepeatButton rb = null;
private RepeatButton rb1 = null;
private Thumb thumb = null;

public ThumbnailUserControl()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  //sv1 repensented as ScrollViewer's object
  this.sv1.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(sv1_Loaded);
}

void sv1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        FrameworkElement fe = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.sv1, 0) as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe == null)
            return;
        var sb = fe.FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
        if (sb != null)
        {                
            thumb = (Thumb)((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sb, 0)).FindName("VerticalThumb");
            rb1 = (RepeatButton)((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sb, 0)).FindName("VerticalLargeDecrease");
            rb = (RepeatButton)((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sb, 0)).FindName("VerticalSmallIncrease");
            rb.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(rb_Click);
            thumb.DragCompleted += new DragCompletedEventHandler(thumb_DragCompleted);
            thumb.MouseWheel += new MouseWheelEventHandler(thumb_MouseWheel);
        }            
}
```